# Console logging for React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor, logging, jsx

I'm super new to React and I'm trying to get it set up for [Meteor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meteor_%28web_framework%29) and piecing stuff together from other sources too.

One of these other sources set up console logging for the app, but I'm going the [ES6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#6th_Edition_%E2%80%93_ECMAScript_2015)/[JSX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/React_(web_framework)#JSX) way, so just using their code wouldn't work for me (or it doesn't seem like it does).

Some code I found for logging is:

```
import Logger from 'simple-console-logger';
Logger.configure({level: 'debug'});
```

But I'm seeing this error:

[image: Cannot find module './dumy']

I also tried using `react-logger` and `react-console-logger` to no avail. Here's my code for the latter, which I believe should work.

```
import {Logger, ConsoleLogger} from 'react-console-logger';
const myLogger = new Logger();
export default class App extends Component {
    render() {
        myLogger.info('something witty');
    }
}
```

However, `myLogger.info('...')` is making a call to `node_modules/react-console-logger/lib/Logger.js` which has it defined as

[image: picture of code since copy-paste doesn't work]

And `this.logger` is undefined, although I see it be defined above?

What am I doing wrong? It looks to me like the library has it wrong, but maybe it has something to do with me using JSX files instead of JavaScript?

Comment: Do you need logging just to help debug / write your code or is this more of a permanent fixture?

Comment: Just to help debug. I can do without, but if I can't even get console logging to work, I'm not sure I can get anything to work...

Comment: No need to reinvent the wheel. This is the best link that explains all. https://codeburst.io/react-native-debugging-tools-3a24e4e40e4

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/40647361/edit) (it covers answers as well). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 133, accepted):

If you're just after console logging here's what I'd do:

```js
export default class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log('I was triggered during componentDidMount')
  }

  render() {
    console.log('I was triggered during render')
    return ( 
      <div> I am the App component </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Shouldn't be any need for those packages just to do console logging.

Comment: You can even add styles to your console.log message. Try this `console.log('%c color message', 'color: #f0c002')`

Comment: Its no doubt fantastic answer but I'm getting warning: `Unexpected console statement  no-console`

Comment: @adi that would be likely caused by ESLint - http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-console

Comment: I would be concerned to use console.log all over my app. I'd rather use something similar to what @adinutzyc21 was trying to use, as using some logging component that allows to control the log level for an app is generally good practice. For my project I used [watson/console-log-level](https://github.com/watson/console-log-level) and I didn't run into any issues using that.

Comment: @RafałNowosielski Generally I only use `console.log` while debugging a specific issue and then they are removed. ESLint also has a rule which enforces removing them. If there is a need for additional logging / monitoring then some other way would be definitely recommended.

Comment: To add to Rafals comment, I was able to use the watson console-log-level component like the following:
`import Logger from 'console-log-level';

let log = Logger({level: 'trace'});
`
See https://github.com/watson/console-log-level

Comment: This is not shown in the console. No filters applied.

Comment: To make the example complete, put it in `src/App.js` and add two imports `import React from 'react';import { Component } from "react";`

Answer (score 129):

Here are some more console logging "pro tips":

**console.table**

```
var animals = [
    { animal: 'Horse', name: 'Henry', age: 43 },
    { animal: 'Dog', name: 'Fred', age: 13 },
    { animal: 'Cat', name: 'Frodo', age: 18 }
];

console.table(animals);
```

[image: console.table]

**console.trace**

Shows you the call stack for leading up to the console.

[image: console.trace]

You can even customise your consoles to make them stand out

```
console.todo = function(msg) {
    console.log(‘ % c % s % s % s‘, ‘color: yellow; background - color: black;’, ‘–‘, msg, ‘–‘);
}

console.important = function(msg) {
    console.log(‘ % c % s % s % s’, ‘color: brown; font - weight: bold; text - decoration: underline;’, ‘–‘, msg, ‘–‘);
}

console.todo(“This is something that’ s need to be fixed”);
console.important(‘This is an important message’);
```

[image: console.todo]

If you really want to level up don't limit your self to the console statement.

Here is a great post on how you can integrate a chrome debugger right into your code editor!

https://hackernoon.com/debugging-react-like-a-champ-with-vscode-66281760037

Comment: Tiny script to automate fancy consoles: [console-colors](https://github.com/yairEO/console-colors)

Comment: Don't forget ``console.dir()`` for arrays and objects!

Answer (score 21):

If you want to log *inside* JSX, you can create a dummy component
 which plugs where you wish to log:

```js
// Some component with JSX and a logger inside
const App = () =>
  <ul>
    {[...Array(4)].map((v, i) => (
      console.log(i), <li key={i}>{i+1}</li>
      )
    )}
    {console.log(123)}
  </ul>

// Render
ReactDOM.render(<App />, root)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Or for fun, as a Component:

```js
const Console = prop => (
  console[Object.keys(prop)[0]](...Object.values(prop))
  ,null // ➜ React components must return something
)

// Some component with JSX and a logger inside
const App = () =>
  <div>
    <p>imagine this is some component</p>
    <Console log='foo' />
    <p>imagine another component</p>
    <Console warn='bar' />
  </div>

// Render
ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("react")
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```