# React, console.log and render display different values

Tags: reactjs

It appears that the **object logged to console** does not match what is **displayed on the HTML**, I'm puzzled by this simple example below. Here the button toggles the ordering of the array, and React seems to render the previous list.

=== Update 3 ====

The cuprite is object compassion where `setState(list=>list.push(12))` will mutate the list but won't trigger setState because the id of the list is still the same.

> If you update a State Hook to the same value as the current state, React will bail out without rendering the children or firing effects. (React uses the Object.is comparison algorithm.) [React useState doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#bailing-out-of-a-state-update)

=== Update 2 ====

I think I found the solution. The culprit seems to be the mutability of objects, and the workaround is to create a deep copy of the sorted list in [Solution Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sorted-list-is-not-rendering-forked-0z7qy?file=/src/App.js). I believe I found an undefined behaviour of React, since the mutability of list should not cause any differences in `console.log(list)` and `<h1>list</h1>` shown in the image below. [Correct modification of state arrays in ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26253351/correct-modification-of-state-arrays-in-reactjs)

[image]

=== Update 1 ====

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sorted-list-is-not-rendering-forked-pu5i7?file=/src/App.js) which contains the same code as the one shown below.

There is nothing wrong with my sort function! If ascending, then the smaller element should come first, which means the comparison function `(e1,e2)=>e1-e2` is correct.

> If compareFunction(a, b) returns less than 0, sort a to an index lower than b (i.e. a comes first). [Comparision function Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

```js
const {useState, useEffect, useReducer} = React;

function App() {
  const [list, setList] = useState([0,1]);
  const [isAscending, toggle] = useReducer(isAscending=>!isAscending, true);
  // update the order of the list
  useEffect(()=>{
    if (isAscending) {
      setList(list.sort((e1,e2)=>e1-e2));
    } else {
      setList(list.sort((e1,e2)=>e2-e1));
    }
  },[list, isAscending]);
  // render
  return (
    <div>
    {console.log("list[0] should be",list[0])}
    <button onClick={toggle}>{isAscending?"Ascending":"Descending"}</button>
    <h1>list[0]: {list[0]}</h1>
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.querySelector('.App'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div class='App'/>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

according to MDN javascript sort function mutates array.

> The sort() method sorts the elements of an array in place and returns
> the sorted array.

when you write:

```
setList(list.sort((e1, e2) => e1 - e2));
```

you are mutating list before setList mutate it.

setList check if given value is different from previous then render.

but setList sees no different since the list value is already updated by sort method.

because of this, render seems one step behind.

so you should write:

```
setList([...list].sort((e1, e2) => e1 - e2));
```

one more thing:

i think you should change

```
{isAscending ? "Ascending" : "Descending"}
```

to

```
{isAscending ? "Descending" : "Ascending"}
```

since it is a toggle button

Comment: "setList check if given value is different from previous then render".

Could you reference this?

Comment: From my knowledge, even if you `setList(previous=>previous)` it still will trigger a re-render

Comment: setList(previous=>previous) will not trigger re-render as we see in this sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/check-render-of-list-if-update-to-prev-value-g21ll?file=/src/App.js

Comment: about the quote, you mentioned i couldn't find a valid reference. i reached this by Trial and error.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I found the reference and posted in the question. I think the API documentation should be more explicit.

Comment: @Chuan: Please check if there is any infinite loop with this fix. Since I went thought that "solution" too before changing to my actual answer.

Comment: Yeah. There is an infinite loop because I placed list as the dependency for the useEffect that updates the list.

Answer (score 2):

Your initial order is ascending order. When you click the button, the first time for toggling the order you want to move from ascending to descending order.

Which means

```
if (isAscending) {
    // Logic for descending should come here
    setList(list.sort((e1, e2) => e2 - e1));
} else {
    // Logic for ascending should come here
    setList(list.sort((e1, e2) => e1 - e2));
}
```

Check the code here and let me know if this is what you were looking for.
[Code Sandbox: Sorted List is Not Rendering](https://codesandbox.io/s/sorted-list-is-not-rendering-i5y7g?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Sorry, the console.log is still different from what is displayed.

Answer (score 1):

You have closure on `list` value at the `useEffect` callback, you should add it to your dep array:

```
function App() {
  const [list, setList] = useState([0, 1]);
  const [isAscending, toggle] = useReducer((isAscending) => !isAscending, true);

  useEffect(() => {
    setList(list.sort((e1, e2) => (!isAscending ? e1 - e2 : e2 - e1)));
  }, [list, isAscending]);

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={toggle}>
        {isAscending ? "Ascending" : "Descending"}
      </button>
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(list)}</pre>
    </div>
  );
}
```

> Note that if you have `eslint` you should get a warning on it.

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-template-forked-08eft?file=/index.js:99-684

Comment: I have updated to include list as a dependency but it didn't seem to have any effect on the code snippet in the original question.

Comment: You also have a bug in the sort callback, check my example

Comment: Sorry. I don't see any bugs in my question

Comment: Your answer is wrong. If you add `console.log(list)` to line 14, you will notice that the list logged and the list rendered are different.

Comment: To log stuff you don't put it in the render function... Log it in `useEffect`

Comment: Why you shouldn't log things inside the return value? Could you support your claim? I assume the render function is the return value.

Comment: It also makes no sense to log things inside useEffect. Since useEffect is async, when it prints the state might have already changed. Using your example https://codesandbox.io/s/q-64520983-closureinuseeffect-forked-2r6n2

Comment: Please read React docs, this question might help you too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59841800/react-useeffect-in-depth-use-of-useeffect/59841947#59841947

Comment: Yo. You just referenced another of your own answer that doesn't explain why you can't log inside JSX. I don't see React doc that says "don't log inside JSX". Here is an answer that logs inside JSX https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40647361/console-logging-for-react

Comment: There is a difference between logging inside render function (functional component body) OR inside the Component tree ("inside JSX") like you did, the render function runs on every render (that's what you want) the JSX tree only changes on diff algorithm

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223859/discussion-between-chuan-and-dennis-vash).

Answer (score 1):

I simplified your snippet just a bit.

You were strangely using both `useState` and `useReducer` while the second is an alternative to the first.

> useReducer is usually preferable to useState when you have complex state logic that involves multiple sub-values or when the next state depends on the previous one.

Quoted from [Reactjs docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#additional-hooks)

```js
const {useReducer} = React;

function App() {
  const list=[0,1]
  const [isAscending, toggle] = useReducer(isAscending=>{
  
    if (isAscending) {
      list.sort((e1,e2)=>e2-e1)
    } else {
      list.sort((e1,e2)=>e1-e2)
    }

    return !isAscending
  }, list);

  // render
  return (
    <div>
    {console.log("list[0] should be",list[0])}
    <button onClick={toggle}>{isAscending?"Ascending":"Descending"}</button>
    <h1>list[0]: {list[0]}</h1>
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.querySelector('.App'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div class='App'/>
```

So here `list` is the `initialState` of the documentation example. And the logic to re-order the list, which is now real simple, is inside the reducer function.

Hoping that helps! ;)

Comment: Thanks for the response, but that does not explain why console.log has a different output than what is shown on html.

Comment: Running `useState` and `useReducer` in parallel certainly is the reason... React does state updates in batch... It would hazardous for to explain .oO(lol) but read [that](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous)